Oracle REST json db, do not see the record but can patch it
I am testing Oracle Autonomous Json Database REST using Soda for access via c# (Unity3d) and all works good.
The process I use is:

Create a json document with a time stamp, works
Update the time-stamp regular, works

However, when I create a new record I cannot see it via OCI (JSON) but I can read and update that record. It takes quite a long time until I can see it, maybe it is cached.
I wrote some code to list all current records in this json collection:
> PlayerId: Jtm7EBceqzoSJLSfX6v37WOLHUyn
> PlayerName: PeterX
> StartTime: 10/29/2024 5:09:20 PM
---------------------------------
> PlayerId: Jtm7EBceqzoSJLSfX6v37WOLHUyn_
> PlayerName: ANONYMOUS NEW
> StartTime: 10/28/2024 8:15:48 PM
---------------------------------
> PlayerId: aaaaaaaaaa
> PlayerName: ANONYMOUS#1
> StartTime: 10/25/2024 4:22:55 PM
---------------------------------
PlayerId: bbbbbbbbbb
PlayerName: ANONYMOUS#2
StartTime: 10/29/2024 7:16:26 PM
---------------------------------
> PlayerId: ABCD
> PlayerName: MaxPax
> StartTime: 10/29/2024 9:49:36 PM
---------------------------------
PlayerId: 1234
PlayerName: MaxPax2
StartTime: 10/29/2024 7:20:31 PM
---------------------------------
PlayerId: 
PlayerName: 
StartTime: 10/29/2024 9:38:11 PM
---------------------------------
> PlayerId: ZÅÄÖ
> PlayerName: Linnéa
> StartTime: 10/29/2024 10:06:34 PM
---------------------------------
PlayerId: MmMmMmMm
PlayerName: UKRAINA
StartTime: 10/29/2024 10:42:21 PM

I can only see the records marked with ">".
I just refreshed OCI approx. one hour after I created records but it is still not updated.
And now, many hours later, the missing records have appeared so I can see them in OCI. I guess this is some delays in OCI.
Can someone please explain why this is happening?
script
The "°" is a bit strange as of now but I will implement Tuple in my binding code in Unity Cloud Code before going further.
using Unity.Services.CloudCode.Core;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace PlayerActive;

public class MyModule
{
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
// URL to the Oracle SODA database
private const string url = "https://aaaaaaa-xxxx-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/xxxx/soda/latest/PlayerActive";

[CloudCodeFunction("PlayerActive")]
public async Task<string> PlayerActive(string token, string playerId, string playerName)
{
    var _idResponse = await GetPlayerDbJsonId(token, playerId);

    if (_idResponse.Contains("200°")) //  200°671bc5e00add524f797af11b
    {
        string result = _idResponse.Replace("200°", "");
        var _patchReturn = await PatchPlayerRecord(result, token);
        return _patchReturn;
    }
    else if (_idResponse == "404")
    {
        var myPayload = new PlayerValue
        {
            playerId = playerId,
            playerName = playerName,
            startTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ"),
            isOnline = true
        };
        
        string payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myPayload);
        
        var _returnCreateRecord = await CreatePlayerActiveRecord(payload, token);
        return _returnCreateRecord;
    }
    else
    {
        return _idResponse;
    }
}

async Task<string> GetPlayerDbJsonId(string token, string playerId)
{
    // Set the Authorization header with Bearer token
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    
    try
    {
        // Create JSON query to search for playerId
        var queryJson = new JObject
        {
            ["playerId"] = playerId
        };

        // Prepare HTTP content for POST request
        StringContent content = new StringContent(queryJson.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        
        // Send POST request to search the database
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url + "?action=query", content);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        
        // Parse JSON response
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
        JArray items = (JArray)json["items"];
        
        int _code = (int)response.StatusCode;

        if (items.Count > 0 && items[0]["value"] != null && items[0]["value"]["_id"] != null)
        {
            // Return only _Id from the first matching document’s value field
            return _code.ToString() + "°" + items[0]["value"]["_id"].ToString();
        }

        // Return null if no matching playerId is found
        return _code.ToString(); //"404";
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Request error: {e.Message}");
        return e.ToString();
    }
}

async Task<string> PatchPlayerRecord(string documentId, string token)
{
    string jsonPatch = $@"[
        {{
            ""op"": ""replace"",
            ""path"": ""/startTime"",
            ""value"": ""{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ")}""
        }}
    ]";
    
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        // Set authorization header
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

        // Specify PATCH endpoint with the document key (documentId)
        string patchUrl = $"{url}/{documentId}";

        // Create HTTP content for the PATCH request
        StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonPatch, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");

        try
        {
            // Send PATCH request
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PatchAsync(patchUrl, content);

            // Check if the update succeeded
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Document updated successfully.");
                int _code = (int)response.StatusCode;
                return _code.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to update document. Status: {response.StatusCode}");
                int _code = (int)response.StatusCode;
                return _code.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Request error: {e.Message}");
            return e.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
}

async Task<string> CreatePlayerActiveRecord(string _payload, string token)
{
    try
    {
        // Set the Authorization header with the provided access token
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

        // Create content with JSON payload and specify content type as application/json
        var content = new StringContent(_payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        // Send POST request to the specified endpoint
        var urlResponse = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

        // Check if the response status indicates success
        if (urlResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            int _code = (int)urlResponse.StatusCode;
            return _code.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            // Log error content if available
            var errorContent = urlResponse.Content != null ? await urlResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() : "No content";
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {urlResponse.StatusCode}, {errorContent}");
            int _code = (int)urlResponse.StatusCode;
            return _code.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        // Log request-specific errors
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        return e.Message; // Service Unavailable
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log general exceptions
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        return ex.ToString(); // Internal Server Error
    }
}
}

public class PlayerValue
{
    public string playerId { get; set; }
    public string playerName { get; set; }
    public string startTime { get; set; } // Changed to string for direct assignment
    public bool isOnline { get; set; }
}


you are committing your transactions?

I checked that and using Soda you do not need to commit: When using Oracle REST SODA (Simple Oracle Document Access) to create a document in a JSON database and add it to a collection, you usually do not need to explicitly commit if you are using the REST API. The Oracle REST API handles commits automatically after a transaction is completed. However, if you are using SODA within an Oracle client (such as PL/SQL or another language that supports SODA libraries), you may need to perform an explicit commit depending on how the session handles transactions.

please share what you're doing, like...how are you doing this, exactly "However, when I create a new record"
